# Formatting output so that Intellij Idea shows diffs for two texts

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to be able to print in the logs a message for which intellij idea would present a nice way of comparing two objects (strings). This happens automatically for the error message logged by a failed junit assert:

```
assertEquals("some\nString", "another\nString");

=>
org.junit.ComparisonFailure:  <Click to see difference>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:145)
    at com.something.DummyTest.testDummy(DummyTest.java:89)
```

The <Click to see difference> entry is actually displayed as a link in the output window of the Intellij Idea. When you click on the link, a compare window opens which shows the two values (just like you would compare two files).

Simply throwing an exception is not acceptable because I would like to log multiple objects to compare. I already tried logging a text, but I wasn't able to convince idea to compare the two texts.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA is using the hardcoded regular expression. If the text matches the pattern, it will suggest to click to view the difference.

The pattern is:

```
expected:<bla-blah> but was:<blah-blah-blah>
```

Output should match the format of `assertEquals` or `assertThat`.

The exact patterns are somewhat scattered around the code in IDEA, but some are e.g. [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/3f7e93e20b7e79ba389adf593b3b59e46a3e01d1/plugins/testng/src/com/theoryinpractice/testng/model/TestProxy.java#L50).

Comment: I think that both values need to be sourrunded by quotes as well.

Comment: @yankee Actually, when looking at the regex pattern, that does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: No quotes necessary, but I had to add a space after the : for this to work. So: `expected: <bla-blah> but was: <blah-blah-blah>`

Comment: Should this still work? I think I found [the new patterns](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/ea2b2d7677106b8d7cdd26d499e5ddd57c73f7f5/plugins/junit_rt/src/com/intellij/junit4/ExpectedPatterns.java#L34) but I don't see any diff buttons. Do I also need to have a crash and/or run it via JUnit to see the diff links?

Comment: @phant0m yes, it has to be an assertion in JUnit tests.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, so multiple diffs in one output isn't possible then?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same Problem and found the solution in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1364#issuecomment-440800958

You should throw an `org.junit.ComparisonFailure`. Then IntelliJ will display the `<Click to see difference>`